# Renaming existing folder in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio

I already have a folder that contains UserControls in my WinForms project. But now I need to rename those folders.

I have done it by right clicking on folder and rename it but I can't refer to the new name.

Old names:

[image]

New names:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the folders does not change the namespaces, which is what you posted. If you renamed them in solution explorer in Visuals Studio, you don't need to change anything. If you renamed it in Windows Explorer, click the "show all files" button, right click on the folder, and click "include in project".

(And next time, you should ask questions like this on Stack Overflow to get more responses.)

Comment: thanks for responding. But didn't work ,so I tried to create another folder (test) then copy all usercontrol in (client) to the new folder then delete the (client) folder, BUT cant find using ParcInfo.test and the old one using ParcInfo.Client is still working

Comment: it work by changing the name space using this https://i.imgur.com/OjR0mJo.png